# AS3 null object error on movie clip 1009 cannot access

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, methods, sprite, nullreferenceexception

Hello I was wandering if someone could help, I keep getting this error spat back at me when I try to launch something in as3. Do I need to import something? Apologies, I originally learned AS2 and I'm now slowly learning AS3.

baby steps.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at draganddropframe1_resetter2_0_fla::MainTimeline/frame3()
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()

this.window_mc.visible = true;

this.windwo_mc.offwindow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shutwin);

function shutwin(event:MouseEvent):void

{ 
    this.window_mc.visible = false;
}
```

UPDATES -----------

A method that appears to have worked around it by changing the direct path to 'this'. Clicked inside the movieclip, added a layer called actions and inserted this script that referenced the movieClip I wanted to hide when clicked.

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToHide);

function fl_ClickToHide(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Good to know you've solved your problem. In StackOverflow, you can post your solution as your answer to this question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATES ----------- "from me "

A method that appears to have worked around it by changing the direct path to 'this'. Clicked inside the movieclip, added a layer called actions, and inserted this script that referenced the movieClip I wanted to hide when clicked.

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToHide);

function fl_ClickToHide(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.visible = false;
}
```

Place this script inside the Movie.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means an object, (moveiclip, variable, etc ) doesn't exist.

Go to your publish settings, and check the box that says "permit debugging".  Then when you get that error in your output window it will also display the exact line number the error occurred on. That line will probably tell you what object is null.

Comment: Hello Ribs, thanks for the pointer. I already have that debugger window open, I can see where it is but I don't know what is causing the issue...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typographical error in your second line. This line

```
this.windwo_mc.offwindow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shutwin);
```

should be

```
this.window_mc.offwindow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shutwin);
```

You've interchanged **w** and **o**.

Otherwise, I would suggest doing Ribs's answer.

Comment: Have you checked which object is causing the null reference?

Comment: I believe it is this, //this.window_mc.visible = false; 
I still can't work it out and bet it is simple issue or something that I have failed to declare.

Comment: check to see if your reference to `window_mc` is not null. If it isn't, check if `offwindow` isn't null. Then work your way from there

Comment: Hi. It seams that I have got something working. I removed the script from frame 3 of the time line and placed inside the window movieClip itself, which appears to have fixed it... for now. 
I will add the code to the top.